# Why isn't my discord bot sending messages?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I coded a part of a bot for discord that supposed to send a message every minute, but after launching the bot, and waiting one minute, the bot still has not sent a message.

I have not tried anything, because I do not know how to fix this problem.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client()
```

```
client.on('ready', function() {
    console.log(client.user.username);
});

client.on('message', function(message) {
    if (message.content === "$loop") { 
      var interval = setInterval (function () {
        message.channel.send("123")
      }, 1 * 1000); 
    }
});

// token taken out of question for privacy
```

I expect the bot to be able to send a message (123 in this case) every one minute.

Comment: `1 * 1000` means it will send a message every one second

Comment: According to the docs, there is an `error` event and a `debug` event. I would start there: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client

Comment: @BrandonDyer so what would be every one minute?

Comment: @amateur_coder see the answer I posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code worked perfectly for me, though it sent a message every second.

The time given to `setInterval` is in milliseconds.

If one second is 1000 milliseconds then 60 seconds is 1000 x 60.

This worked for me:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client()

client.on('ready', function() {
    console.log(client.user.username);
});

client.on('message', function(message) {
    if (message.content === "$loop") {
        var interval = setInterval(function () {
            message.channel.send("123");
        }, 60 * 1000);
    }
});

client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

I would also recommend looking into arrow functions, and discord.js's debug events.

Comment: So in the ```client.login(process.env.TOKEN);``` part, where would I put my token?

Comment: should I only replace the capital letters with my token?

Comment: @amateur_coder when you start the bot in the command line, you use the token. This way you keep the token out of the code. `TOKEN=ABCDEFG node ./index.js`

Comment: Yout put the token in the command prompt, yes. That whole line. Though, you should have a script in your package.json, so you can run `TOKEN=ABCD npm start`

Comment: When I run ```TOKEN=mytoken node ./my_bot.js``` It returns ```'TOKEN' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.```

Comment: Oh yeah, Windows is a thing. There are a couple of options. The first is to use `set TOKEN=yourtoken` then run `node ./my_bot.js` or set TOKEN in your system environment variables.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197635/discussion-between-amateur-coder-and-brandon-dyer).

Answer (score 0):

can we make like a data folder and a config.json inside data folder after

```
const config = ('./Data/Config.json');
```

after

```
*inside config.json
 
{
    "token": "ur token here"
}
```

*inside bot.js

```
client.login(config.token);
```